# Plot several MatrixPlots as "timeline" using Manipulate

Tags: plotting, matrix, manipulate, visualization

I am currently struggling with a relatively simple problem, however, unfortunately, I am not as familiar as others with the Mathematica syntax.

I would like to use `Manipulate` to `Show`several `MatrixPlot`'s I have created beforehand. I named the plots according to their year and now would like to Show them with a bar, which can be used to switch between the years (can be animated one after annother).

`Manipulate[ Show[plot2008, plot2009, plot2010, plot2011, plot2012,plot2013], {Year, 1, 6}]`

I am sure this is pretty wrong, as I did not define that every year is equal to one plot, but I could not find a solution online how to tackle this problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards
Alex (

Answer (score 5):

Make a list of your plots, then index into the list.

```
allPlots = {plot2008, plot2009, plot2010, plot2011, plot2012, plot2013}; 
Manipulate[allPlots[[year]], {year, 1, 6, 1}]
```